# SeekBarPreference show value while dragging and not only after

Tags: android

I have added a SeekBarPreference for numeric input, and it is showing the current value just fine.
I can drag it to a new position and the display is updating.

My issue is that it is not updating *while* it is being dragged, which makes it difficult to hit a precise value, when you cannot see how far you are before ending drag.

There are a lot questions/answers about SeekBarPreference but, as far as I can tell, none about this particular issue. I am aware that for AndroidX there are solutions, with continous update flags, but I am currently stuck on supportLibrary v7 where I see no such options.